# command-not-found does not complain about unknown commands in zsh

Tags: command-line, zsh

I installed the `command-not-found` package and am loading it in my `.zshrc` like so:

```
source /etc/zsh_command_not_found
```

While I now get suggestions for commands that are not found but can be obtained by installing additional packages (e.g. `asdf`), I no longer get *any* feedback when a command is not found *and* there are no suggestions that provide that command (e.g. `asdfasdfadfasdf`). In that case, there is absolutely no output on the command line and so I often don't notice when a command is not run. (For instance, I didn't want Conda to modify my shell environment by default but that means that I have to source the Conda shell script whenever I want to use the `conda` command. Now I often only notice three commands down the line that I actually forgot to source that script and that my conda calls didn't do anything.)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a copy of `/etc/zsh_command_not_found` in your home directory:

```
cp /etc/zsh_command_not_found ~/.zsh_command_not_found
```

Open it using your desired editor:

```
vim ~/.zsh_command_not_found
```

Remove the `--no-failure-msg` flag from this line:

```
/usr/lib/command-not-found --no-failure-msg -- ${1+"$1"} && :
```

So it should look like this:

```
/usr/lib/command-not-found -- ${1+"$1"} && :
```

Save and close the editor.

Instead of sourcing `/etc/zsh_command_not_found`, source `~/.zsh_command_not_found` in your `.zshrc`.

```
user@focal ~ % source ~/.zsh_command_not_found 
user@focal ~ % csh

Command 'csh' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install csh   # version 20110502-5, or
sudo apt install tcsh  # version 6.21.00-1

user@focal ~ % conda
conda: command not found
```

---

<sub>I'm not a `zsh` user, so I've got no idea why `--no-failure-msg` is being passed to the `/usr/lib/command-not-found` by default.</sub>

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't expect at all that `--no-failure-msg` was actually desired behavior.